# Problem creating a discord bot for rolling dice

Tags: python, discord

This is my first trying creating a discord bot. I want it to work like this:

User:

/roll 2d20+4

Then my bot will roll 2d20, save the sum and the bigger. Finally, it will print like this:

Output:

Bigger: 16+4=20 | Sum: 23+4=27.

This is the code I have:

```
import hikari
import lightbulb
import random

disc_token="..."
server_id="..."

bot=lightbulb.BotApp(
    token=disc_token,
    default_enabled_guilds=int(server_id)
)



@bot.command
@lightbulb.command('roll',"Role dados (exemplo: 2d20+5)")
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.SlashCommand)

async def roll(ctx,play):
    die_split=play.split("d")
    final_split=die_split[1].split("+")
    n_die=int(die_split[0])
    die=int(final_split[0])
    extra=int(final_split[1])
    play=[n_die,die,extra]
    best_roll=0
    sum_roll=0
    for i in range(n_die):
        actual_roll=random.randint(1,die)
        sum_roll=sum_roll+actual_roll
        if(actual_roll>best_roll):
            best_roll=actual_roll
    sum_roll=sum_roll+extra
    extra_roll=best_roll+extra
    play_print='Bigger: '+str(best_roll)+'+'+str(extra)+'='+str(extra_roll)+' | Sum: '+str(sum_roll)
    
    await ctx.respond(play_print)

bot.run()
```

What is happening:

The bot is working (I tested some basic commands, like "Hello World" and works fine), but when I try to run the /roll command, for the discord user it shows:
"! The app did not answered".
At my terminal, the error was displayed like this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\MateusRochaQSOFT\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\lightbulb\app.py", line 1163, in invoke_application_command
await context.invoke()
File "C:\Users\MateusRochaQSOFT\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\lightbulb\context\base.py", line 328, in invoke
await self.command.invoke(self)
File "C:\Users\MateusRochaQSOFT\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ligh    raise new_exc
lightbulb.errors.CommandInvocationError: An error occurred during command 'roll' invocation

What could be wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "but is not responding to the /roll command." What exactly does this mean? For example, are you able to check whether the `roll` function gets called? Is it? "I tested some basic commands" - okay, and **what is different** about those commands? What happens if you try to add parts of the logic to one of those commands, a step at a time, until it does what the roll command should do? Where is the actual sticking point? Please read [ask] and [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: I will update my post

Comment: Is it sending the response at all? What input are you using? I have tried running the code (without the discord context though as I have never used `lightbulb` before) and it works fine for the input you have provided.

Comment: @ESloman the inputs in Discord are strings like I mentioned:

/roll 2d20+5 for instance.

I  tested the function it self out of Discord and it works, but in Discord it doesn't respond. I  think that there is a mistake in the way I wrote it  for discord

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback for the error you're getting? That might have more information in and help us decipher what is wrong.

Comment: I updated my post with the traceback

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I'm using the Discord in portugueses, I translated it, but I searched online and looks like that is the warning message in english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're defining your options wrong for using the `lightbulb` package. You have to define the options using the `@lightbulb.option` decorator and can then access them via `ctx.options`. Where the name of the option is the property you can get.

```py
@bot.command
@lightbulb.option("play", "dice roll")
@lightbulb.command('roll',"Role dados (exemplo: 2d20+5)")
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.SlashCommand)
async def roll(ctx):
    play = ctx.options.play
    die_split = play.split("d")
    final_split = die_split[1].split("+")
    n_die = int(die_split[0])
    die = int(final_split[0])
    extra = int(final_split[1])
    play = [n_die,die,extra]
    best_roll = 0
    sum_roll = 0
    for i in range(n_die):
        actual_roll = random.randint(1, die)
        sum_roll = sum_roll + actual_roll
        if actual_roll > best_roll:
            best_roll = actual_roll
    sum_roll = sum_roll + extra
    extra_roll = best_roll + extra
    play_print = f"Bigger: {best_roll} + {extra} = {extra_roll} | Sum: {sum_roll}"
    await ctx.respond(play_print)

bot.run()
```

Found in the [documentation here](https://hikari-lightbulb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/commands.html#the-option-decorator). You can access the `play` variable using `ctx.options.play`.

I've also formatted the code to use [PEP8 formatting](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) and I used [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) in place of the string concatenation that you were doing.

You can also use the [`pass_options`](https://hikari-lightbulb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/commands.html#the-command-decorator) parameter in `@lightbulb.command` to pass all the defined options (via decorators) as keyword arguments.

Like this:

```py
@bot.command
@lightbulb.option("play", "dice roll")
@lightbulb.command('roll',"Role dados (exemplo: 2d20+5)", pass_options=True)
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.SlashCommand)
async def roll(ctx, play):
```

This way you don't need to do `play = ctx.options.play`.